# Ler um vetor até um bit de parada

Tags: c, array, for, binary

Quero ler um vetor binário de 8 bits de trás para frente, e parar até que leia o último `1`.

Por exemplo: `[00010101]` <--- Ler até encontrar o ultimo `1`

Vetor lido: `[1010]`

Depois associar uma função para cada `1` lido e outra função para cada `0`.
Como faço? Como ficaria os parâmetros dentro de um `for`?

Comment: @rod_learninh, bem-vindo ao SOpt, seria interessante você postar o código de sua tentativa para que o pessoal te ajude :D

Comment: Isso é o mesmo que ler da frente para trás a partir do primeiro `1` ... e depois "inverter" o valor.

Comment: Pergunta repetida (em inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668476/reading-a-binary-vector-backwards-with-a-stop-bit

Answer (score 1):

Ola, Bom dia!

Fiquei com dificuldades de entender sua pergunta, mas pelo que percebi, você deseja ler os '1' e '0' de tras para frente até parar no ultimo 1 e coloca-los num vetor novo.(v1).

Realizei um programa para exemplificar minha solução utilizando um vetor de caracteres, ja que é binário só teremos dois carateres (1 e 0).
Utilizei a função malloc da biblioteca stdlib para dimensionar o vetor no tamanho de 8 bits. (n = 8).
n1, i e j são variaveis auxiliares para realizar a leitura inversa do vetor.

Segue o código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*Desenvolva as funções como desejar*/
void funcaoAssociada1 () {
}

void funcaoAssociada0 () {
}
int main () {
   char *v, *v1;
   int i, n, j, n1;
   n = 8;
   j = 0;
   n1 = 0;
   v = malloc (n * sizeof (char));
   v1 = malloc (n* sizeof (char));
   printf ("Digite o vetor binário (sem espaços)\n");
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      scanf ("%c", &v[i]);
   for (i = n-1; i >= 0; i--,j++)
      if (v[i] == '1') n1 = j;
   for (i = 0; i <= n1; i++)
      v1[i] = v[n-1-i];

   v1[i-1] = '\0';/*Caractere nulo, indica fim do vetor*/
   printf ("%s",v1);

   for (i = 0; v1[i] != '\0'; i++)
      if (v1[i] == '1') funcaoAssociada1 ();
      else funcaoAssociada0 ();
   free (v1);   
   return 0;
}
```

Espero que tenha sido útil.
Qualquer dúvida comente.

MS